# Deustch-Jozsa algorithm for a specific problem, doesn't make sense?

Tags: programming, quantum-gate, quantum-algorithms, deutsch-jozsa-algorithm

I am trying to implement Deustch-Jozsa Algorithm where function f(x) = 0 for even and f(x) = 1 for odd, for a four-bit number. After writing the numbers out I found a pattern as described below
[image]

Therefore as you can see the from the image, all I need to do is add the CNOT gate to the last register so to implement the oracle and here is my circuit that I have written for the same. Here is the circuit and output for the same
[image]

[image]

My question is shouldn't the output be '1111' since this is a balanced function. The number corresponding in the circuit is 2 = '0010' and the output is showcased for the same. I would highly appreciate breakdown. Also the does the circuit implement the oracle where f(x) = 0 is even and for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your oracle is correct. The mistake here is that you initialized $q_1$ to $|1\rangle$ instead of the ancilla qubit. So the proper circuit here would be something like [this](https://algassert.com/quirk#circuit=%7B%22cols%22%3A%5B%5B%22H%22%2C%22H%22%2C%22H%22%2C%22H%22%2C%22X%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22H%22%5D%2C%5B%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22X%22%5D%2C%5B%22H%22%2C%22H%22%2C%22H%22%2C%22H%22%5D%2C%5B%22Measure%22%2C%22Measure%22%2C%22Measure%22%2C%22Measure%22%5D%5D%7D):

[image]

This would give the state $|1000\rangle$ with probability $1$, which shows that $f(x)$ is balanced.

For your second question, recall that Deutsch-Jozsa algorithm guarantees that either the final measurement will give $|0\rangle^{\otimes n}$ with probability $1$, in which case our function is constant, or it will yield some other state, in which case we have a function that's balanced. Our measured state **need not** be $|1\rangle^{\otimes n}$ to deduce that $f(x)$ is balanced.

Comment: so the reason for me initializing the Q1 -> to |1> is because I was trying to encode the input to number 4 which corresponds to |0100> from the table I created in the first image. Also The reason I didn't initialize the ancilla qubit to |1> is because whenever the number is odd I want the oracle to output |1> and if it is even I want |0>. As you can see from the image above for even numbers the last qubit is always |0> therefore for even it will output |0>, but for odd numbers the last digit is |1> changing the output to |1> for the output. Again would appreciate clarification if not correct.

Comment: @JaZZyCooL I don't understand what you mean by encoding an input. The only thing Deutsch-Jozsa expects is an oracle $U_f$ which maps $|x\rangle |y\rangle \to |x\rangle |y\oplus f(x)\rangle$ and given that it determines if $f$ is balanced or constant. It accepts no other input. Also, you need the ancilla to the state $H|1\rangle$ in order to induce phase kickback.

Comment: @JaZZyCooL You can read more about Deutsch-Jozsa [here](https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-algorithms/deutsch-jozsa.html).

Comment: I am sorry I should have made it clear basically for even number values my oracle should output 0 and for odd number values oracle should output 1, which is why I kept the anicalla qubit to |0> since natually for even numbers the last digit is qubit is |0> which makes the oracle keep the f(x) to 0 and only change to |1> if the last qubit is |1>. Basically f(x) is a four bit function where for even number f(x)=0 and for odd f(x)=1 and using Deutsch-Jozsa I am trying to figure out whether it is balanced or not. Therefore, for oracle giving me the correct output I kept ancilla |0>

Comment: @JaZZyCooL That's exactly what a single CNOT does. Remember that you want to map $|x\rangle|y\rangle$ to $|x\rangle |y\oplus f(x)\rangle$. Check all the basis states to see that the CNOT gate does exactly that. For example, $|11\rangle$ will be transformed to $|10\rangle$ which is exactly $|1\rangle|f(1)\oplus 1\rangle$. Other than that, the initialization to $H|1\rangle$ is there to induce phase kickback and is independent of the specific oracle.

Comment: I see that makes a lot of sense thank you :)